# Image stitching issue generated while using OpenCV in iPhone

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, ios7, image-stitching

I am working on stitching an image using OpenCV. I am using four images having size of **"720 × 960 pixels"**. From four images I have used three images which is going to be stitched when app gets launched. and the fourth one will stitch when I tap on stitch button. It is working fine. But the issue gets raised when I'm changing the size from **"720 × 960 pixels to 640 × 960 pixels"** of all four images and again I run the code after resizing images the three images has been shown same way that I have mentioned above, but while I tap on a stitch button from where I have to stitch the fourth image, compiler shows a message in console as mention below-

> **Can't stitch images, error code = 1**
>
> **<Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.**

I have used following code-

**In CVViewController.h**

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CVViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *arrayImgGlobal;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView* spinner;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrollView;
@end
```

**In CVViewController.m**

```
#import "CVViewController.h"
#import "CVWrapper.h"

@interface CVViewController ()

@end

@implementation CVViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated    
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSArray* imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"1@2x.jpg"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"2@2x.jpg"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"3@2x.jpg"],
                            nil];
    [self stitch:imageArray];
}

-(IBAction)onButtonStitch:(UIButton *)btn
{
    [self onBtnStitchPressed:arrayImgGlobal];
}
-(void)onBtnStitchPressed:(NSArray *)imageArray
{
    [self stitch:imageArray];
}

- (void) stitch : (NSArray *)imageArray
{
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
              UIImage* stitchedImage = [CVWrapper processWithArray:imageArray];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSLog (@"stitchedImage %@",stitchedImage);
            for (UIImageView *imgView in [self.scrollView subviews]) {
                [imgView removeFromSuperview];
            }
            UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:stitchedImage];

            self.imageView = imageView;
            [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
            self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.bounds.size;
            self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
            self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
            self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width-self.imageView.bounds.size.width)/2, -(self.scrollView.bounds.size.height-self.imageView.bounds.size.height)/2);
            NSLog (@"scrollview contentSize %@",NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.contentSize));
            [self.spinner stopAnimating];

            NSArray *arrayImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    stitchedImage,
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"4@2x.jpg"],
                                    nil];
            arrayImgGlobal = arrayImages;

        });
    });
}
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - scroll view delegate

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
@end
```

Code that I have used in my project over [Here](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch)

**One more thing-
I have tested my code along with above link's code in ios 7.0 simulator. while I'm running it into the device it just shown message in console which I have above mentioned.**

Can someone please tell me where I might be going wrong and how to fix it? Thanks